# Highcharts update pointRange, pointWidth after initial render

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to update the pointRange on a column type [HighCharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) chart, which has already been rendered?

Seems like it would be a common request, but I can't get it to work..

```
chart.options.plotOptions.column.pointRange
chart.options.plotOptions.column.pointWidth
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/PRKAJ/ for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `update()` function

```
 chart.series[0].update({
        pointWidth:10,
        pointRange:10
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PRKAJ/6/
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()